# Адаптивное видео с Vimeo

Tags: html, css, html5, видео

Доброго времени. Хочу вставить на сайте видео с Vimeo и сделать его адаптивным.
iframe помещаю в блок с классом video:

```css
.video {
  width: 556px;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /*пропорции видео 16:9 */
  padding-top: 25px;
  height: 0;
  background: red;
}

.video iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/254988878" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
         </iframe>
</div>
```

Но iframe по высоте почему-то получается намного больше, чем само видео, и кнопка загрузки видео вверху находится.

В чем может быть проблема, как это исправить?

Когда с youtube вставлял видео таким способом, то все было нормально, там правда не iframe

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нарисовал `padding`- ов  и спрашиваешь почему не так как хочу. Как сверстал так и выглядит....

```css
.video {
  width: 640px;
  position: relative;
  height: 360px;
  background: red;
  padding: 5px;
}

.video iframe {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/254988878" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>
         </iframe>
</div>
```